# How to use ORDER BY on aggregate column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

This is my mysql statement:

```
select distinct(prodname), 
       sum(qty) 
from tblordertrail 
group by prodname;
```

the result is:

```
+----------+------------+
| prodname |  sum(qty)  |
+----------+------------+
| product1 |  27        |
| product2 |  77        |
| product3 |  198       |
| product4 |  34        |
+----------+------------+
```

But the result I want is:

```
+----------+------------+
| prodname |  sum(qty)  |
+----------+------------+
| product3 |  198       |
| product2 |  77        |
| product4 |  34        |
| product1 |  27        |
+----------+------------+
```

thanks in advance my fellow programmers.

Comment: actually I got already the result, I just want to DESC the sum(qty) column

Comment: right, that is what the question this got marked as a duplicate of explains.